# How can I sum two columns in SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table with 2 columns:

```
CREATE TABLE Numbers(
    col1 float,
    col2 float
);
INSERT INTO Numbers(col1, col2)
VALUES('0.6', '1.5'),('2.7', '1.8');
```

How can I create a third column with the sum of col1 and col2?

Comment: Are you looking for [generated columns](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table-generated-columns.html)?

Answer (score 0):

First, create col3 using the ALTER TABLE command.

Then update it with the sums.

```
UPDATE numbers SET col3 = col1 + col2;
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest a calculated column - that way if col1 or col2 are updated, col3 will automatically reflect the correct value; storing mutable data is gnerally not a good idea as it easily leads to inconsistencies.

```
alter table Numbers add column col3 float as (col1 + col2) stored;
```

Side note - *float* is rarely the correct choice of data type, *probably* you should be using a *decimal*.

Answer (score 0):

---

Select *, col1 +col2 as col3 from numbers

---

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).